# Biblatex: customizing the bibliography

Tags: biblatex

I am using `biblatex` for referencing. My code and output is as follows:

Source code:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[top=1in,bottom=1in,left=1.25in,right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{times}


%___________________________________________
\usepackage[maxbibnames=99,bibstyle=authoryear,style=numeric-comp,doi=false, isbn=false,giveninits,terseinits=true,url=false]{biblatex}
\DeclareNameAlias{author}{family-given}
\renewcommand*{\revsdnamepunct}{}
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\addspace and \addspace}
\renewbibmacro{in:}{}
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}
\addbibresource{reference.bib}
%___________________________________________

\begin{document}
\noindent Impact of cyclone in human health \cite{dissanayake1991} and concentration graph \cite{mukherjee2018groundwater}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Output is:
[image]

`reference.bib` file:

```
@article{dissanayake1991,
    title={The fluoride problem in the ground water of Sri Lanka — environmental management and health},
    author={Dissanayake, CB},
    journal={International Journal of Environmental Studies},
    volume={38},
    number={2-3},
    pages={137--155},
    year={1991},
    publisher={Taylor \& Francis}
}
@article{mukherjee2018groundwater,
  title={Groundwater fluoride contamination, probable release, and containment mechanisms: a review on Indian context},
  author={Mukherjee, Indrani and Singh, Umesh Kumar},
  journal={Environmental geochemistry and health},
  volume={40},
  number={6},
  pages={2259--2301},
  year={2018},
  publisher={Springer}
}
```

My questions are:

1. Is it possible to bring the year after the author names? If yes, how can I do it?
2. Is it possible to remove the period after the author names, title, journal name (except the period at the end of each reference)? If yes, how can I remove those periods?

Any help is very much appreciated!!

Comment: For future posts, please consider splitting up your issues into separate questions. Ideally one question should only be about issue. The two points here are independent and can be answered separately. See also https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7425/35864

Comment: @moewe I understood. I will ask separate questions next time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The year can be moved to after the author names by copying the relevant code from `authoryear.bbx`, which has the year after the author, (see comments in the code below, the copied code is slightly simplified: the `dashed` option was removed).

Most periods in the example output were produced by `\newunit`'s `\newunitpunct`, so if you redefine `\newunitpunct` you can change those periods. This may be too radical (also for other entry types), in which case one would have to go over to more complex solutions, where single `\newunit`/`\setunit` instances in the bibliography macros or drivers are changed.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[top=1in,bottom=1in,left=1.25in,right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{times}


\usepackage[backend=biber,
  style=numeric-comp,
  maxbibnames=99,
  giveninits, terseinits=true,
  doi=false, url=false, isbn=false,
]{biblatex}

\DefineBibliographyExtras{english}{%
  \def\finalandcomma{}}

\renewcommand*{\revsdnamepunct}{}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}

%%%% adapted (simplified) from authoryear.bbx
\DeclareNameAlias{author}{sortname}
\DeclareNameAlias{editor}{sortname}
\DeclareNameAlias{translator}{sortname}

\DeclareNameWrapperAlias{author}{sortname}
\DeclareNameWrapperAlias{editor}{sortname}
\DeclareNameWrapperAlias{translator}{sortname}

\renewbibmacro*{author}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test \ifuseauthor
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{author}}
  }
    {\printnames{author}%
     \setunit{\printdelim{authortypedelim}}%
     \usebibmacro{authorstrg}%
     \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}}%
    {\usebibmacro{labeltitle}%
     \setunit*{\printdelim{nonameyeardelim}}}%
  \usebibmacro{date+extradate}}

\renewbibmacro*{editor}{%
  \usebibmacro{bbx:editor}{editorstrg}}
\renewbibmacro*{editor+others}{%
  \usebibmacro{bbx:editor}{editor+othersstrg}}
\newbibmacro*{bbx:editor}[1]{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test \ifuseeditor
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{editor}}
  }
    {\printnames{editor}%
     \setunit{\printdelim{editortypedelim}}%
     \usebibmacro{#1}%
     \clearname{editor}%
     \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}}%
    {\usebibmacro{labeltitle}%
     \setunit*{\printdelim{nonameyeardelim}}}%
  \usebibmacro{date+extradate}}

\renewbibmacro*{translator}{%
  \usebibmacro{bbx:translator}{translatorstrg}}
\renewbibmacro*{translator+others}{%
  \usebibmacro{bbx:translator}{translator+othersstrg}}
\newbibmacro*{bbx:translator}[1]{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test \ifusetranslator
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{translator}}
  }
    {\printnames{translator}%
     \setunit{\printdelim{translatortypedelim}}%
     \usebibmacro{#1}%
     \clearname{translator}%
     \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}}%
    {\usebibmacro{labeltitle}%
     \setunit*{\printdelim{nonameyeardelim}}}%
  \usebibmacro{date+extradate}}

%% mergedate=compact
\renewbibmacro*{date}{%
  \usebibmacro{bbx:ifmergeddate}
    {}
    {\printdate}}%

\renewbibmacro*{date+extradate}{%
  \iffieldundef{labelyear}
    {}
    {\printtext[parens]{%
       \iflabeldateisdate
         {\printdateextra}
         {\printlabeldateextra}}}}%
\renewbibmacro*{bbx:ifmergeddate}{\iflabeldateisdate}%
\renewbibmacro*{issue+date}{%
  \ifboolexpr{test {\usebibmacro{bbx:ifmergeddate}}
              and
              test {\iffieldundef{issue}}}
    {}
    {\printtext[parens]{%
       \printfield{issue}%
       \setunit*{\addspace}%
       \usebibmacro{bbx:ifmergeddate}
         {}
         {\printdate}}}%
  \newunit}
% authoryear.bbx END

\renewbibmacro{in:}{}
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}

% remove period in most places
\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addspace}


\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{dissanayake1991,
  title   = {The Fluoride Problem in the Ground Water of {Sri Lanka}
             -- Environmental Management and Health},
  author  = {Dissanayake, CB},
  journal = {International Journal of Environmental Studies},
  volume  = {38},
  number  = {2-3},
  pages   = {137--155},
  year    = {1991},
}
@article{mukherjee2018groundwater,
  title   = {Groundwater Fluoride Contamination, Probable Release,
             and Containment Mechanisms: a Review on {Indian} Context},
  author  = {Mukherjee, Indrani and Singh, Umesh Kumar},
  journal = {Environmental geochemistry and health},
  volume  = {40},
  number  = {6},
  pages   = {2259--2301},
  year    = {2018},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Impact of cyclone in human health \autocite{dissanayake1991}
and concentration graph \autocite{mukherjee2018groundwater}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: [1] Dissanayake C “The Fluoride Problem in the Ground Water of Sri Lanka – Environmental Management and Health” International Journal of Environmental Studies 38.2-3 (1991), 137–155.//[2] Mukherjee I and Singh UK “Groundwater Fluoride Contamination, Probable Release, and Containment Mechanisms: a Review on Indian Context” Environmental geochemistry and health 40.6 (2018), 2259–2301.]

---

An alternative slightly shorter, but also slightly more dangerous method would be to select `bibstyle=authoryear,` and then manually input the code for `bibstyle=numeric,`.

Since `bibstyle=authoryear,` has code to move the year in a position directly after the author and `bibstyle=numeric,` inherits most of the current setup and just adds numbers, this works.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[top=1in,bottom=1in,left=1.25in,right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{times}


\usepackage[backend=biber,
  bibstyle=authoryear,
  citestyle=numeric-comp,
  maxbibnames=99,
  giveninits, terseinits=true,
  doi=false, url=false, isbn=false,
]{biblatex}

\DefineBibliographyExtras{english}{%
  \def\finalandcomma{}}

\renewcommand*{\revsdnamepunct}{}

\makeatletter
\input{numeric.bbx}
\makeatother

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}

\DeclareNameAlias{author}{sortname}
\DeclareNameAlias{editor}{sortname}
\DeclareNameAlias{translator}{sortname}

\DeclareNameWrapperAlias{author}{sortname}
\DeclareNameWrapperAlias{editor}{sortname}
\DeclareNameWrapperAlias{translator}{sortname}

\renewbibmacro{in:}{}
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}

% remove period in most places
\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addspace}


\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{dissanayake1991,
  title   = {The Fluoride Problem in the Ground Water of {Sri Lanka}
             -- Environmental Management and Health},
  author  = {Dissanayake, CB},
  journal = {International Journal of Environmental Studies},
  volume  = {38},
  number  = {2-3},
  pages   = {137--155},
  year    = {1991},
}
@article{mukherjee2018groundwater,
  title   = {Groundwater Fluoride Contamination, Probable Release,
             and Containment Mechanisms: a Review on {Indian} Context},
  author  = {Mukherjee, Indrani and Singh, Umesh Kumar},
  journal = {Environmental geochemistry and health},
  volume  = {40},
  number  = {6},
  pages   = {2259--2301},
  year    = {2018},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Impact of cyclone in human health \autocite{dissanayake1991}
and concentration graph \autocite{mukherjee2018groundwater}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```